# Interact with several ModelEntities

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

Is there an easy way to interact with several ModelEntities in RealityKit at the same time? for example rotate two ModelEntities with one multi-touch gesture.

Comment: you can make the two the children of a upper entity, then rotate the upper one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. Just create a parent entity for two or more children.

```
let parentEntity = Entity()
parentEntity.addChild(childEntity01)
parentEntity.addChild(childEntity02)
    
arView.installGestures([.all], for: parentEntity as! Entity & HasCollision)
```

P. S.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418011/is-there-a-way-to-let-an-entitytranslationgesturerecognizer-recognize-touches-on/75419095#75419095) will show you how raycasting works in conjunction with RealityKit gestures.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10428c3a0)` on the `arView.installGestures([.all], for: parentEntity as! Entity & HasCollision)` line. I changed parentEntity to ModelEntity and it's fixed now.